# Multiple Markers on OpenLayers using Javascript

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, markers

Using Openlayers 2.13, I am trying to set up multiple markers for New expatriates in our suburb.

As a new user of both JS and Openlayers, I am stuck - I have managed one marker but cannot add another - do I need to upgrade to Openlayers 4 or use an array?

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>OpenLayers Solution</title> 
    <script src="OpenLayers.js"></script> 
    <script>       function init() { 
    var lat            = -1.3169;
    var lon            = 36.6903;
    var zoom           = 15;

    var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
    var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform( fromProjection, toProjection) ;

    map = new OpenLayers.Map("Map");
    var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    map.addLayer(mapnik);

    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position));

    map.setCenter(position, zoom);
    }
</script> 
 </head> 
<body onload="init();"> 
 <div style="width: 100%; height: 60%;" id="Map"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add another marker, you'd call `markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position));` again, but this time with a new `position` argument (otherwise the markers would appear on top of each other).

As for upgrading to OpenLayers 4, you should do that simply because OpenLayers 2 is no longer supported, won't be receiving bug fixes or updates, and the community knowledge of OpenLayers 2 is going to become stale; you'll have more and more trouble finding help.